# I can't use clear or remove function in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

So i was trying to use clear function of kotlin while building an app in android studio though clear is kotlin built in function it is giving an unresolved reference error my code is:

```
Var peerListListener= WifiP2pManager.PeerListListner(){
val refreshedPeers= peerList.deviceList
If(!refreshedPeers.equals(peers)){
Peers.clear()
}
}
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and this code is done outside the oncreate function

peers is defined as:

```
var peers:List<WifiP2pDevice>=mutableListof<WifiP2pDevice>()
```

I have tried declaring this both globally and locally

Comment: You are upcasting your MutableList to a read-only List when you assign it to the property defined as just a List. Since List is read-only, the mutating functions like `clear()` are hidden from you. Remove `:List<WifiP2pDevice>` from your property declaration.

Comment: Thank you that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you got typo, you're defining the variable as `peer` but trying to use clear on `Peer`.
Second you're exposing `peer` as an immutable list by saying `List<WifiP2pDevice>` and `List` interface does not have clear as it is immutable. Expose `peer` as mutable list by defining it as `MutableList<WifiP2pDevice>` and you will be able to use `clear()`.

Comment: List is not necessarily immutable. It is read-only. Immutability would imply that the contents are guaranteed to be the same every time you read from it. But you could be reading from a MutableList that has been upcast to List, so some other object could be changing its contents.

Comment: Could not agree more, that's why I said that the field is exposed as a List, from peer's perspective it's immutable as it cannot change it. If the same instance were to be exposed by another field as a MutableList and it changes the list at some point, the change would be of course reflected to the peer itself as both fields point to the same list, but one is exposing it as a read-only the other one can mutate it.

Comment: The word *immutable* means a class is guaranteed to have content that never changes, not just that the current view of the class doesn't expose mutating functions. List does not provide that guarantee. From peer's perspective, the list is read-only, but it is not immutable. Peer can read from the list twice and see different results.